# Added last name and search functionality in Customer Grid

Tags: customer, grid, name

Currently, only first name show on 'Customers -> Manage Customers' admin page if there are a lot of same first name user, it's hard to find right customer at once

How can I make show last name `on 'Manage Customers' admin page? Between Name and Email column`

(last name should be also searchable like other field)

Comment: are you talk about customer grid?

Comment: Customers -> Manage Customers menu , Is it called customer grid?

Comment: I have give answers with steps.

Comment: thethirdmoon,this called customer grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per Magento Standard.

In Manage Customer Grid you can see the Full name with `Prifix FirstName LastName`.

You have to override the Customer Grid and Add new Field In grid.

Step 1: `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php` Copy this file to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php`.

Step 2: Find `_prepareColumns()` method in this file.

Step 3: added below code.

```
  $this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'lastname'
    ));
```

Step 4 : and comment below lines.

```
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
```

Step 5: You can search with now Name and LastName also.

There is another way is also you can override the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` and added this filed also.

Thanks let me if any question.

Comment: It works like a charm! and easy step by step guide!! Great Solution Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you  customer grid  collection comes from  `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()`h then this collection will consist of `firstname and lastname` in collection  then you can `first name and list name easily`

**just copy**

**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php**

to
**app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php**

**add this code in _prepareColumns()**

```
$this->addColumn('lastname', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
            'index'     => 'lastname'
        ));
```

Comment: Can I know what file and line I have to add that code? Thank you Amit!!

Comment: in grid.php _prepareColumns function after  $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));

Comment: Solved! Thank you!